# Defining function with index

Tags: functions

I have the following relation:
[image]

(i=1,...,q).
For defining li, I write:

```
l[i_] := 2 R Sin[\[Phi][i]/2]
```

where R is the radius of a circle, l[i] is the i-th length of the secant of the circle defined by the apex angle Phi. The index [i] allows for indicating the i-th considered angle.

Is it correct?

Comment: hard to tell, is R a variable? what is phi? is l_i a function? Please provide more information if you want a sensible answer.